# Have two overlapping controls receive same click event?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid with two overlapping UserControls:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ControlA Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.RowSpan="2"
              Canvas.ZIndex="1"
              Background="Transparent"/>
    <ControlB Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

Both have click and scroll behavior and listen to MouseDown/MouseWheel events, ControlB also has it's own VisualTree with child controls that should receive those tunneling and bubbling events (ControlA is rather simply, but still need those events).

Clicking on the non-overlapping part works fine and intended, but when I click on the overlapping part I can only have either one of those receive the events, not both as I want them.

I tried to catch the Preview-Events and delegate them to to the child controls, but till now I haven't found a way that doesn't lead in no behavior at all, or a StackOverFlow.

```
//Does not work
private void OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlA.RaiseEvent( new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left){RoutedEvent = MouseDownEvent} );
        ControlB.RaiseEvent( new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, MouseButton.Left){RoutedEvent = MouseDownEvent} );
    }
```

Do I have to manually implement `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest()` and go through the visual tree? Do I have to make the the ControlA backgroung null and force the events for it (as it lacks a VisualTree of children), while ControlB can use normal tunneling and bubbling?

How can I send the events in a natural way (so no forced commands completely replacing the Event system) to **both** controls?

Comment: Why not simply use `ControlA.RaiseEvent(e);`?

Comment: Lead to recursive StackOverFlow as it would raise the Grid.PreviewMouseDown event again for some reason. Creating new Args prevented this. 

Comment: Unless `ControlB` is a Logical Child of `ControlA` you can't tunnel or bubble the events from one control to another. You need to raise those events manually.

Comment: They're logically siblings, and it would make little sense to have them parent/child (in either configuration). So I have to raise the events, how? My posted way doesn't work as intended. Maybe I'm just using the wrong syntax or method?